# Contents indexing going mad and getting mixed up

Tags: sectioning, environments, chapters, indexing

I am having some big problem regarding the table of content of my thesis and the indexing of the propositions. I think it mainly began when I introduced chapters, whereas I only used sections before.

This is how my table of contents looks like [image]

The indexing makes no sense at all. 
Similarly the counters of Definitions, Propositions and so on seems to have related problems, take for example

[image]

where I would instead like the section to be 2.2 and the definitions to be 2.2.1 and 2.2.2: the problem seems that I am generating the same order for chapters, sections, definitions and so on.

This text code is in fact located in

```
\chapter{Fundamentals of Set and Order Theory} %which is the second chapter: so far so good$
\section{Axiomatics of Set Theory} %which appears as 2.1: ok%
\section{Orderings} %which apears as section 2.4 instead of 2.2: this is no coincidence since the previous section contains exactly 2 definitions%
```

This is the code I am using regarding new enviroments

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{myth}[section]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{myprop}[section]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[section]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[section]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{myrmk}[section]{Remark}
\newtheorem{myex}[section]{Example}
```

The impression is that all the indexing is getting mixed up peculiarly, without respecting the natural hierarchy (chapter,section...)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe `\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]` and `\newtheorem{myprop}[mythm]{Proposition}` (and similarly for the other environments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
\newtheorem{myth}[section]{Theorem}
```

orders LaTeX to use for `myth` the `section` counter. So each time `myth` is used, the section counter steps up. The same for the other environments.

You most likely want

```latex
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section] % myth is subordinate to section
\newtheorem{myprop}[myth]{Proposition} % myprop shares the myth counter
\newtheorem{mylemma}[myth]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[myth]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{myrmk}[myth]{Remark}
\newtheorem{myex}[myth]{Example}
```

But why using such strange names? Wouldn't `theorem` be better than `myth`?

Comment: Thanks, definitely what I was searching for, and what I had actually written before someone corrected me wrongly, because of a reference related issue.